# Dynamic permissions to users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working with existing code for an asp.net web page in which the methods in the controllers are restricted according to the role the user is in, as such:

```
    namespace Principal.Controllers
    {
       [Authorize]
       public class MyController: Controller
       {
          [Authorize(Roles = "Role1,Role2,Role3")]
          public method1() {...}
       }
    }
```

The problem is the part where the roles allowed are declared:

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Role1,Role2,Role3")]
```

I would like to make the string dynamic, so I can return it from a method depending on properties set by an admin, however it keeps giving me weird errors, such as "Error  3   An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type"

Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you discovered, you can only use constants when defining attributes; this is due to the fact that the attribute is compiled into the code - you cannot use expressions that the compiler does not know at compile time.

What you could do instead, is to create a new attribute inheriting from  the `AuthorizeAttribute` class, and overriding `OnAuthorize`. Then you can implement your custom role logic here.

Comment: Exactly what I would recommend. However I would add that if all you want to is make the roles dynamic, you should be able to simply get away with overriding the `OnAuthorization` and populating the Roles string with what ever roles you need to then just call `base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);`